# NullPointerException while querying a hbase external table in hive

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive, cloudera, hue

Attempting to get skill about the hadoop project and all its modules, I am trying to do this (using cloudera):

-Create a mysql table filled with something like 12k rows
-Importing it in hbase with sqoop
-Find a way to use those data for analysis (I thought that create an external hive table pointing would have been a good idea)

So I am stuck with the last point. I can create an external table of hbase in hive with this code:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ViewSimulation (
  id int,
  eol int,
  sensor int,
  value1 float,
  value2 float,
  value3 float,
  value4 float,
  value5 float,
  value6 float)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "hbase.columns.mapping" =
  ":key,data:eol,data:sensor,data:value1,data:value2,data:value3,data:value4,data:value5,data:value6"
)
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "Simulation");
```

I do it in console because I have a problem with hue. For no apparent reason, it can't connect to zookeeper, I have this error looping again and again (plus all the usual error following it).

```
13/12/09 06:52:25 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
13/12/09 06:52:25 INFO util.RetryCounter: Sleeping 2000ms before retry #1...
13/12/09 06:52:27 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
13/12/09 06:52:27 INFO util.RetryCounter: Sleeping 4000ms before retry #2...
13/12/09 06:52:32 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
13/12/09 06:52:32 INFO util.RetryCounter: Sleeping 8000ms before retry #3...
13/12/09 06:52:40 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
13/12/09 06:52:40 ERROR zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries
13/12/09 06:52:40 WARN zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    .............
```

The response is just "OK" so I figure that everything went fine here.
But when I do a simple "select * from viewsimulation", I get the following error message:

```
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.NullPointerException
Time taken: 0.735 seconds
```

Or, depending on which machine I query with, a big freeze and this error message when I kill the process:

```
OK
Interrupting... Be patient, this might take some time.
Press Ctrl+C again to kill JVM
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: Giving up trying to location region in meta: thread is interrupted.
```

Reconfiguring zoo.cfg (cloudera missed all "server.id = host:port:port" lines for unknown reasons...) made me able to create the external table on console (for some machine, not all of them...) but not in hue, and I still can't query it. I have not a clue of what is wrong with my cloudera's configuration, or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Hue as a [tutorial](http://gethue.tumblr.com/post/64707633719/hadoop-tutorial-use-pig-and-hive-with-hbase) for creating Hive tables stored into HBase. Have you checked the listed dependencies?

Comment: Thanks for this tutorial, looks pretty nice ! Do you know what version is he using (or maybe it's you, I noticed that the github page is yours :p) ? Because I have a different view of Hue (blue top menu, less consistent left hive menu...). Also, I noticed the using of localhost quorum with zookeeper, doesn't that mean that the table won't be reachable if we have a replicated hbase table ?

Comment: Well, I can't go through the 1st step of this tutorial. I can create external tables with the console but not with Hue, still have the KeeperException$ConnectionLossException looping again and again. Seems like my Hue configuration isn't fine.